# OpenMapTiles auth not working

Tags: openstreetmap, openmaptiles

When I try to log in via GitHub or google I get the following messages

[image]

, and OpenMapTiles refuses to let me login.

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("default-src").
iframe.html:1
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("default-src"). Source: .vimvixen-console-frame {
  margin: 0;

 Received message: !_{"h":"I0_1529357937694"} from https://openmaptiles.firebaseapp.com
client.js:181:7
Received message: trunc
!_{"s":"/I0_1529357937694::_g_restyleMe","f":"I0_1529357937694","r":"I0_1529357937694","t":"33540592","c":2,"a":[{"setHideOnLeave":false}],"g":false} from https://openmaptiles.firebaseapp.com
client.js:181:7
Received message: !_{"s":"__cb","f":"I0_1529357937694","r":"I0_1529357937694","t":"33540592","c":null,"a":[4,[null]],"g":false} from https://openmaptiles.firebaseapp.com
client.js:181:7
Received message: !_{"s":"__cb","f":"I0_1529357937694","r":"I0_1529357937694","t":"33540592","c":null,"a":[3,[true]],"g":false} from https://openmaptiles.firebaseapp.com
client.js:181:7
Received message: !_{"s":"/I0_1529357937694::authEvent","f":"I0_1529357937694","r":"I0_1529357937694","t":"33540592","c":3,"a":[{"type":"authEvent","authEvent":{"type":"signInViaRedirect","eventId":null,"urlResponse":null,"sessionId":null,"postBody":null,"error":{"code":"auth/network-request-failed","message":"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}}}],"g":false} from https://openmaptiles.firebaseapp.com
client.js:181:7
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from secured workspace?

Comment: @dennis no - this is from a residential address

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem unrelated to the OpenMapTiles project.

Based on the error, it seems to me some of your extensions is colliding with the login iframe.

There is something about `vimvixen` in the console. Try disabling it (or other extensions).

Answer (score -1):

It's because the application is down - it's using : http://openmaptiles.firebaseapp.com/ which is not running.

I guess this project is dead, or sleeping.